# spark-rest in apache-camel 2.14: how can I use ? and & in GET url

Tags: rest, apache-spark, apache-camel

I have an apache-spark REST endpoint within Camel route configured e.g. as:

```
 rest("events/").description("myrest")
                .produces("application/json")
                .get("{number}").description("Returns stuff") 
                .to("bean:reportEventQueryService?method=getDataByNumber(${header.number})");
```

that can be called as **localhost:8080/events/1** and returns data.

How I can configure this route so that I can have URLs with ? and &, such as:
**localhost:8080/events?eventId=1&bigReport=true**

Note: I have Camel 2.14 and it is  difficult to upgrade to newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a 2nd get as `get("{numbers}")` requires you to provide a number, eg `/2` etc. It cannot match when there is no number (the context path is empty).

So the 2nd get can be

```
 .get().description("Returns stuff")
```

And then you can call it with query parameters.

Comment: if I add that 2nd get, where do I find my query line parameters? (eventId=1, bigReport=true etc?)

Comment: They are mapped as Camel headers